# Multi Pattern Matching Algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pattern-matching

Consider you have several patterns of dates P1 - Pn.

Some of them are simple like P1 - all Mondays, P2 - all Tuesdays; others are more complex like P4 - all working days etc.

For custom array of dates (V1, V2) I have to create the shortest result string, as it is shown on the picture:

[image: Multi Pattern Matching]

For any array we have to create string which will represent dates in array. The simplest method is to create string like 1.5.2013, 2.5.2013, 3.5.2013 ... But the result string will be very long.

Using several predefined patterns we can create shorter result string.

> For result string I use following rules:
>
> Single date format: DD.MM.YYYY **(10 characters)**
>   Enumeration (dates and patterns): comma and space **(2 characters)**
>   Interval of dates: DD.MM.YYYY-DD.MM.YYYY **(21 characters)**
>   Interval of pattern names: Px-Py **(5 characters)**
>   Special words: except **(6 characters)**

Examples of result strings:

- V1 using P4 pattern:

  > P4 except 01.05.2013-03.05.2013, 09.05.2013, 10.05.2013, 16.05.2013, 17.05.2013 **(80 characters)**
- V1 using Pn pattern:

  > Pn 06.05.2013-08.05.2013, 13.05.2013-15.05.2013, 20.05.2013-24.05.2013, 27.05.2013-31.05.2013 **(94 characters)**
- V1 using best patterns match:

  > P1-P3 01.05.2013-19.05.2013, P4 20.05.2013-31.05.2013 **(54 characters)**

The main goal is to create the shortest result string. As I understand we can achieve this by finding the best matching pattern/patterns.

Currently I'm trying to adapt knapsack problem and longest common subsequence problem, but I'm not sure if it is the right direction.

I would appreciate any ideas.

---

**updated**

Thanks to **Jan Dvorak** for his extra short description of my problem:

The goal is to describe V using a predefined dictionary (P1..Pn and all intervals and single dates) where intersection, union and subtraction are all allowed and each operation and atom have a predefined cost (number of characters in result string).

---

Comment: Shortest result string for *what*? Please provide an explicit description of the task. From your graphics I for example cannot understand why V2 matches a part of all days, but V1 does not match a part of the work days.

Comment: I have added more information. You can use for V1 pattern P4 (all working days), but the result string will be longer. Result string for V1 using P4 pattern is: P4 from 5.5.2013 to 8.5.2013 and from 13.5.2013 to 15.5.2013 and from 20.5.2013 to 24.5.2013 and from 27.5.2013 to 31.5.2013

Comment: so, your goal is to describe V using a predefined dictionary (P1..Pn and all intervals and single dates) where intersection, union and subtraction are all allowed and each operation and atom have a predefined cost?

Comment: Exhibit one: `P1-P3 from 1.5.2013 to 19.5.2013, P4 from 20.5.2013 to 31.5.2013` (64 characters); Exhibit two: `P4 except 9.5.2013, 10.5.2013, 16.5.2013 and 17.5.2013` (54 characters). Is the latter allowed? If not, why?

Comment: to Jan Dvorak: It look like right description of my problem, but what do you mean by 'predefined cost'?

Comment: @dannikoti predefined cost = how much it counts against "best". As in, date literals cost 9 characters, interval literals cost 22 characters, set difference costs 6 characters ("except")...

Comment: to Jan Dvorak: Your definition is correct.About Exhibit two:  I've made a mistake in post in second example, I've used P4, but ment Pn. V1 using P4 pattern is: P4 except 1.5.2013-3.5.2013, 9.5.2013, 10.5.2013, 16.5.2013 and 17.5.2013 (74 chars) which is longer then P1-P3 from 1.5.2013 to 19.5.2013, P4 from 20.5.2013 to 31.5.2013

Comment: Looking at your date format, your date literals don't have a fixed cost. They can be from 8 to 10 characters depending on whether the day and month are less than 10 or not. Also your date ranges are represented differently for an except ("date1-date2") vs an inclusion ("from date1 to date2"). And while the former combines date ranges with a comma, the latter combines date ranges with " and ". The former also supports a single date, while the latter doesn't appear to do so. A grammar showing exactly what string formats are permitted would make this a whole lot clearer.

Comment: @JamesHolderness I didn't concentrate on the result string format on purpose. Of course it is important to have fixed rules, but now I rather want to know direction. This post already looks complicated, and none of visitors didn't write about method or at least direction how I can solve this problem.

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, but personally I find it difficult to come up with a solution without knowing the full requirements of the problem. Perhaps the exact details wouldn't matter in the end as far as the general approach is concerned, but I find it difficult to work on a hypothetical problem with unknown parameters. Maybe that's just me though.

Comment: Such an interesting question. I think I understand your motivation and that you want to find a general solution without restricting the primitive patterns that could be used. But defining exactly how [complex the primitive patterns](http://xkcd.com/1155/) and the way they can be composed is important for the usefulness (human readability) of the resulting string.

Comment: I've updated post and added rules for result string.

Comment: How about a simple backtracking algorithm to start? See the performance of that. I suspect if your input sizes are small this should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time of searching we finally found solution which is very close to what we want.

http://www.fpz.unizg.hr/traffic/index.php/PROMTT/article/view/1287

Thanks for all how participated.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion but if you want a really short string that represent the arrays of dates, you could solve this problem in a totally different way, this way is very simply and efficient.

Let 1 represent a day "seleceted" and let 0 represent a day "unselected", then you can construct a binary number that represent the custom date arrays in a month, for example, for the V1 case you can generate this binary number:

```
V1 = 0000011100001110000111110011111
```

So the first 0 represent that the date 1.5.2013 is "unselected", the next 0 represent that the date 2.5.2013 is "unselected", etc. If you separate this number in 8 bits groups (dividing the binary number in bytes) then you can create this byte array:

```
V1(starting in May 1, 2013) = 00000111 - 00001110 - 00011111 - 00111110  (4 bytes)
```

With this method you are representing the V1 using just 4 bytes, this is the only info you need if you know that V1 start on the date 1.5.2013, so you need to store the initial date as well, so you can represent the month and year using just 3 bytes, so for instance the May 2013 date can be represented in this way:

May = 5th month so 5 in binary is 101

2013 in binary is 11111011101
So using 3 bytes you can represent May 2013 as this:

```
0000101 00000111 11011101
[  5  ] [     2013      ]
```

So you can represent V1 as this

```
V1= 0000101 - 00000111 - 11011101  00000111 - 00001110 - 00011111 - 00111110
    [Month]   [     Year        ]  [      V1 custom array of dates         ]
```

So V1 can be totally represented using just 7 bytes!!

If you need a String instead of a byte array, then you can convert this byte array into a
Base64 String so V1 can be represented as the string

```
V1 in Base64 is Cg+6Dhw+Pg== (using just 12 characters!!)
```

In the case of V2:

```
V2 = 0000101 - 00000111 - 11011101  11111111 - 11111111 - 11111111 - 11101110
     [Month]   [     Year        ]  [      V2 custom array of dates         ]

V2 in Base64 is Cg+7////bg== (using just 12 characters again!!)
```

With this method you know that a month custom array of dates info can be represented in 7 bytes (or 12 characters if you use the base 64 String).

To store the custom array info in a year you just need:
3 bytes for the start month and year, plus 365/8 = 45.625 (rounded to 46 bytes), that is 49 bytes!! for the whole year, that in base 64 has a maximum length of 69 characters!!!

This is simple to implement, easy to maintain in code, better than a complex pattern matching algorithm, this smell like a good solution to me. I hope that this recommendation fits your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, we use very similar way to store data.